# What's the time complexity of the code snippet below?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

It looks like some sort of a partial-sort.

```
int n = a.length;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    while(a[i] != i) {
        if(a[i] < 0 || a[i] >= n) //avoid stepping out of range
            break;
        if(a[i] == a[a[i]]) //avoid inf loop by duplicates
            break;
        int t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[t];
        a[t] = t;
    }
}
        
return a;
```

On first look, seems like O(N^2) but when I run it seems O(N). Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Elliott No other processing is done to the array for example a = {1, 2, 100, 200}.

Comment: The inner while loop is not dependent on n. Therefore it cannot be O(n^2).

Comment: @lincr, the outer loop? The number decreases *by at least* one. However, on that logic alone it could still be `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 4):

You're right that it's `O(n)`:

---

To help explain this I'll make up a definition:

**Reflective**: An element, `a[i]`, in an array, `a`, is *reflective* if `a[i] = i`.

---

### Iterations of `while` loop that ***do*** result in a `break`:

For each value of `i`, you can have exactly one `break` that's executed within the `while` loop (including the `while` condition). As there's `n` values of `i`, this means there's `n` *total* iterations of the `while` loop that result in a `break`.

### Iterations of `while` loop that ***don't*** result in a `break`:

For this part it might help to imagine our array where each element is either reflective (`1`), or non-reflective (`0`):

### | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Once we have passed the `break` points, then we ***know*** that `a[i] != a[a[i]]` (ie. if we name `a[i]` as `t`, then we know that `a[t] != t`). And because we later assign `a[t] = t`, then we have ***changed*** an element of the array from non-reflective to reflective. Note that nowhere in your code do we make a reflective element non-reflective: The assignment `a[i] = a[t]` could result in `a[i]` being non-reflective, but we also know that it wasn't reflective to begin with because the `while` statement was true: `a[i] != i`.

From our visual, this means that no `1` ever changes to a `0`, and yet every iteration of the `while` loop (that passes the `break` points) results in at least one `0` flipping to a `1`.

Once you observe that every (non-`break`) iteration of the inner loop takes at least one (possibly two) non-reflective elements from the array and converts it to become ***permanently*** reflective, then we realise that the total amount of (non-break) iterations of the inner loop cannot exceed `n` *for the entire run-time of the program*.

---

In summary: `i` is iterated and checked in the `for` loop `n` times, and each does a constant amount of work, `c1`. There's `n` *total* iterations of the iterations of the `while` loop that correspond to a `break`, and at most `n` iterations that don't correspond to a `break`. Hence there's at most `2n` iterations of the `while` loop in total. The work done in a single iteration of the `while` loop is some max constant, `c2`.

Hence time complexity <= `c1*n + c2*2*n` = `O(n)`.

---

As for the function of the code, it rearranges elements to make as many of them reflective as possible: if after this function `a[i]` is non-reflective, then the value `i` isn't present in the array.

Comment: I like answers which go beyond a line of code or a formula by explaining. Nice. ;-)